# df.Commission.value - AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'value'

Tags: python-3.x

I am receiving this error and I cannot figure out what the problem is. I have looked online but still haven't found a solution.

Thank you for your help in advance!

[image: Code]

Comment: Thank you for your help ! :)

Well, I believe I need the .value to make this a numpy array, correct?

If  I remove the .value and continue my code, I receive another error when I try to reshape. "Data must be 1-dimensional" . Doesn't the .value make this on dimensional?

dataset = dataset.astype('float32')
dataset = np.reshape(dataset, (-1, 1))

Comment: Actually, I got it !

dataset  =df.Commission
dataset = dataset.astype('float32')
df1 = np.reshape(dataset.values, (-1, 1))

Answer (score 1):

Every DataFrame column is represented by pandas Series object.
The Series object that you try to refer has no attribute value.
But If you look in the [documentations](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.1/generated/pandas.Series.values.html) there is a method named values that returns the Series values in numpy array. so this should produce the results:

```
dataset = df.Commision.values
```